# Import multiple entries from a module and assign to some alias in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vuetify.js, es6-modules

I want to import several entries from a module and assign to some alias. Is that possible? Currently I do

```
import {
  mdiAlert,
  mdiCheck,
  mdiDelete,
  ... 40 more ...
} from '@mdi/js'

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    values: {
      mdiAlert,
      mdiCheck,
      mdiDelete,
      ... 40 more ...
    }
  }
})
```

Is is possible to `import { one, two, three } as something from 'module'` somehow to avoid code duplication?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot import a few module entries into an object. You need to import the bindings under a local alias and then build the object from them separately.

What you can however do is to import the *complete* module as a namespace object:

```
import * as mdiValues from '@mdi/js'

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    values: mdiValues,
  }
})
```